# How to use numpy fillna() with numpy.where() for a column in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, fillna

Here is an example pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'file': ['filename2', 'filename2', 'filename3', 'filename4', 
         'filename4', 'filename3'], 'amount': [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1], 
         'front': [21889611, 36357723, 196312, 11, 42, 1992], 
         'back':[21973805, 36403870, 277500, 19, 120, 3210], 
         'type':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df1)

        file  amount     front      back type
0  filename2       3  21889611  21973805    A
1  filename2       4  36357723  36403870    A
2  filename3       5    196312    277500    A
3  filename4       1        11        19    B
4  filename4       2        42       120    B
5  filename3       1      1992      3210    C
```

I'm defining a new column `end` using `numpy.where()`:

```
df1['end'] = np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back'])
print(df1)
   amount      back       file     front type       end
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A  43863416
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A  72761593
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A    473812
3       1        19  filename4        11    B        11
4       2       120  filename4        42    B        42
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C      5202
```

I would like to use the same approach to fill in `NaN` values, if the `end` column partially exists, e.g. here is a `DataFrame` where a `end` does exist as a column, but with many `NaN` values. (EDIT: these values that are not NA may be entirely unique):

```
new_df
   amount      back       file     front type       end
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A       NaN
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A       NaN
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A        12
3       1        19  filename4        11    B       NaN
4       2       120  filename4        42    B        49
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C       NaN
```

I would think one could do this with `pandas.DataFrame.fillna()`, but this throws an error:

```
df1['end'].fillna(np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back']), inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2434, in fillna
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3631, in fillna
    type(value))
ValueError: invalid fill value with a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Question: how do I efficiently use `np.where()` only on `NaN` values within a certain column?

Comment: What's exactly the behavior you want? Do you mean you want to continue to fill in values after performing np.where actions?

Comment: @Tai Let's say I were to apply the `np.where()` command on all values within the column `end` in the second example. I would be overwriting values `473812` and `42`

Comment: So you want to leave NaN there without touching it?

Comment: @Tai I think I understand the confusion. See the Edit above. I was to leave the non-NaN values alone, and only apply `np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back'])` to `NaN` valeus

Comment: So what you want is first find the NaN values and then update values that are previously NaN? Thanks for clarifying. Guess you can list desired output above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fillna` is base on index

```
df['New']=np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back'])
df
Out[125]: 
   amount      back       file     front type       end       New
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A       NaN  43863416
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A       NaN  72761593
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A  473812.0    473812
3       1        19  filename4        11    B       NaN        11
4       2       120  filename4        42    B      42.0        42
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C       NaN      5202
df.end.fillna(df.New)
Out[126]: 
0    43863416.0
1    72761593.0
2      473812.0
3          11.0
4          42.0
5        5202.0
Name: end, dtype: float64
df.end=df.end.fillna(df.New)
df
Out[128]: 
   amount      back       file     front type         end       New
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A  43863416.0  43863416
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A  72761593.0  72761593
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A    473812.0    473812
3       1        19  filename4        11    B        11.0        11
4       2       120  filename4        42    B        42.0        42
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C      5202.0      5202
```

Update

```
df['New']=np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back'])
df.end=df.end.fillna(df.New)
df
Out[133]: 
   amount      back       file     front type         end       New
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A  43863416.0  43863416
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A  72761593.0  72761593
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A        12.0    473812
3       1        19  filename4        11    B        11.0        11
4       2       120  filename4        42    B        49.0        42
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C      5202.0      5202
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please see my edit above for `new_df`. I think my first try at this question was somewhat confusing

Comment: @ShanZhengYang for nan the methodology is the same.

Comment: I see. And then one should delete `df.New` afterwards

Comment: @ShanZhengYang you can using drop('New',1) at the end

Comment: There is no need to create and then delete a new series. You can use pd.Series to use the array output of np.where with fillna(). df.end=df.end.fillna(pd.Series(np.where(df1['type']=='B', df1['front'], df1['front'] + df1['back'])))